# Can an Android Phone be used as a Windows Hello Security Key?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, windows-10, yubikey, fido

Microsoft Windows 10 does support [physical security keys since some time](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4463210/windows-10-sign-in-microsoft-account-windows-hello-security-key).

Google [recently announced](https://www.blog.google/technology/safety-security/your-android-phone-is-a-security-key/) that Android phones can be used as security keys as well (primarily for their own services).

Is there a way that these two play together, i.e. can I use a Pixel phone with NFC to unlock a laptop with Windows 10 and a NFC reader?